# Get next year from the current NSDate?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a calendar application in which I want to get the next year from the current date (NSDate).

How can I do this?

Comment: Just get the year from the current date and add one. Which part don't you know how to do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can make `NSDateComponents` do all the hard work of calculating leap years and leap seconds:

```
NSDate *today = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[offsetComponents setYear:1];
NSDate *nextYear = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:today options:0];
```

Answer (score 5):

As VdesmedT mentioned, you can use dateByAddingTimeInterval and add the seconds of one year. But to be more precise, you can do the following:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date]; // get the current date
NSCalendar* cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; // get current calender
NSDateComponents* dateOnlyToday = [cal components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit ) fromDate:today];
[dateOnlyToday setYear:([dateOnlyToday year] + 1)];
NSDate *nextYear = [cal dateFromComponents:dateOnlyToday];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .year, value: 1, to: Date())
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my version: in swift.

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Year, value: 1, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions.MatchNextTime)
```